# Insert data to mysql without duplicate data

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

i want to insert data to MySQL table but i want to check the duplicate same time when i insert data, if there is any duplicates then skip those data and insert the new data to the table, i want a way to do this with a query , please someone help

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the records with a `SELECT` statement before inserting the data or you could just make one of the columns in your table `UNIQUE`.